# Jasmine.js: How to spyOn a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a fromDate text field in my script as:

```
      var fromDate = document.getElementById('fromDate').value;
```

I know how to spyOn this textbox in jasmine.js:

```
    var params = {
    'fromDate': { value: '01/01/2010' },
         };

      beforeEach() {
      spyOn(document, 'getElementById').and.callFake(function (arg) {
            return params[arg];
        });
      }
```

Similarly I am also extracting value from a dropdown list in script as:

```
    var invId = $('#cboInv').find('option:selected').val();
```

Now how do I spy on this? Please help.

Comment: Looks like you need to do something like `spyOn($.fn, "find")` as mentioned in the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060119/spying-on-jquery-selector-in-jasmine   Or Googling for "jasmine spyon jquery selector" returned many hits which might help you. If you find the answer, please mention it here, so that other people can learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to mock it.

Because it is a chained call, in the `spyOn()` function we need another method to mock `val()` also:

```
spyOn($.fn, 'find').and.callFake(function (arg) {
    var valInternal = function () {
        return 'myCustomId';
    };
    return {
        val: valInternal
    };
});
```